# jQuery / AJAX autocomplete, query MySQL table only once per session

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax

I am developing autosuggest(autocomplete) functionality with jQuery / AJAX. The problem is that the MySQL table I will use for this has 30,000 records and the server is highly loaded. So I don't want to query the MySQL table everytime the visitor presses a button, I would rather query it once per user session. Is there an option to achieve this? Maybe caching or retrieving the 30,000 records once and store it somewhere?

Thanks,

Zolka

Comment: use memcache and you should be good

Comment: Should not be problem if it is indexed properly. Maybe try to implement som limitation on how many results will show, that will be added as user scrolls. Also quering after there are at least 3 characters shold make it easier for server.

Comment: You will probably have to implement something like that in your backend (the program/script your AJAX request is sent to). Fetching 30k rows and sending them to each client is probably not the best idea. Sounds like a lot of data. You could maybe create some sort of session and store the fetched rows on the server for each session in a file, but that's pretty much the same as looking in the DB, just with one file per user.

Answer (score 0):

Use cache option. But it works user enter previous value. Other wise it hit the server.

```
$(function() {
    $("#empname").autocomplete(
    'getNames.action',
        {
            scroll:false,
            minChars:1,
            delay:0,
            width:200,
            autoFocus:true,
            cache:true,
            formatResult: function(data, value) {

              return value.split(".")[0];
            }
        });
});
```

Comment: first retrieve all the values from database and save it in session. from second time, instead of sending the request to database, try to search in session object

Comment: Does the above solution do that? I mean cache is set to true so it obviously does some sort of caching.

Answer (score 0):

30,000 records, with a good key, you can get the result pretty fast.

Normally you wouldn't want to do AJAX on every key press, but you need to give a delay for the user to type (e.g. 500ms).

```
var t;
$('#textbox').keyup(function() {
    if (t) clearTimeout(t);
    t = setTimeout(function() {
        // AJAX call here
    }, 500);
});
```